# our app crashed in iOS 9 which upload by Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode10

Our app crashed in iOS 9 which upload to App Store by Xcode 10 GM Seed. It's running perfectly when using XCode 10 GM Debug Or Archive To Ad_Hoc. Here's some call stack.

[image: crash1]

[image: crash2]

[image: crash3]

Is Xcode 10 GM do anything with image.assets or others?

apple reply 
[image: apple reply]

Comment: You'll need to post at least the crash logs in order for anyone to be able to help. There is not much information in this question.

Comment: i send the linked image,but it doesnt show.

Comment: it's crashed below iOS 9.3

Comment: We have got same crash in our application after update to xcode 10.
Application is crashing in random places on iOS 9.1 on start

Comment: @EvgeniyYurtaev Do you have any idea? https://medium.com/@rickynguyen/weird-crash-on-ios-9-0-9-1-9-2-5583c25c7f5b , here is a similarity issue, but i think its not what cause these crashes in this time.

Comment: We haven't found reason of crash. It looks like a memory management issue in our application or iOS 12 SDK. We want to know whether anyone gets this crash

Comment: btw,the app crashed when launch.

Comment: @Fogmeister i have attached some pictures,do u have any idea?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar crash on my app as well on [UIImage imageNamed:] calls only on iOS below 9.3 and it started with the version of the app compiled with Xcode 10 linked against the iOS 12 SDK. None of the code or images have been changed in years and never crashed prior.

Comment: best one download Xcode latest Xcode  10 version then solve out your problem

Comment: @RamaniHitesh the problem is still exist. :(

Comment: which editor  here xcode  10 or Xcode 10 gm seed ?

Comment: latest final people using latest Xcode 10 version not gm seed version.

Comment: @RamaniHitesh we use Xcode 10(10a255) and upload again,also crash below iOS 9.3.

Comment: which time crash please clarify then , i solve ...out

Comment: @RamaniHitesh app on launch,did you use xcode 10 gm upload prior?

Comment: yes use Xcode 10 version and upload many apps ...

Comment: We have got same crash in our application after update to xcode 10、Xcdoe10.1 beta。 I tried the method（https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60919?start=30&tstart=0） but it doesn't work。And if I use Xode 9 it's OK.

Comment: @SuperHappy xcode10.1 has been released?I try to contact apple dts,and they reply,here’s some bug then let us to reporting bug for apple,we did.it does not fix in Xcode 10.1?beta version can upload apps?

Comment: @apricot So, Apple has confirmed that this is a bug from their side? We face the same situation too. Thanks.

Comment: @apricot  Xcode10.1beta have not fix it. We can use Ad Hoc after appthining to test this crash.

Comment: @Raymond I have attached a snapshot of apple reply email on this post. we have report this bug for apple,you can report it also,hope apple can resolve it fast.

Comment: My released apps (using Xcode 10 GM) are also crashing randomly at startup on iOS 9 (below iOS 9.3.x). Seems like the random crashes happen after a view is loaded from storyboard or xib file....... Now preparing to submit again using Xcode 9

Comment: @apricot yes, I already submit it as bug too. Hope they fix it soon!

Comment: I found that delete all *.xcassets file it is fine in iOS9.2.1.So check the image first.

Comment: well done,but It‘s unpractical for us.I think it is the xcasset's problem always.Xcode 10 release note and wwdc said xcassets has been optimized,it is a joke...

Comment: Instead of waiting for Apple to fix, submit using Xcode9 while using NSInvocation for the new API

Comment: ln -s  Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtoold Xcode10app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtoold     this can solve it

Comment: Seems to crash in iOS 9.2.x, 9.1.x, and 9.0.x, and not in iOS 9.3.x.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Edit 4:** From the Xcode 10.2 beta release notes:

> Resolved an issue that affected app compatibility with iOS 9.0, 9.1, and 9.2 when distributing an app for local or enterprise distribution. App asset catalogs built using Xcode 10 with a deployment target of iOS 9.0, 9.1 or 9.2 produced content incompatible with the runtimes of those iOS versions when distributed using local or enterprise distribution. Rebuilding the app with Xcode 10.2 resolves this issue. (46893768, 44535967)

**Edit 3:** From the revised Xcode 10.1 release notes:

> **Asset Catalog**
>
> **Known Issues**
>
> Apps that contain asset catalogs built using Xcode 10 or later with a deployment target set to iOS 9.0, 9.1 or 9.2 produce content incompatible with the runtimes of those iOS versions. (44535967, 45723580, 45723189)

The issue remains. ‍♂️

**Edit 2:** Apparently, the issue is still not completely fixed.

**Edit:** Xcode 10.1 is out now.

This has been fixed in Xcode 10.1 beta 2:

> Resolves an issue that affected app compatibility with iOS 9.0, 9.1 and 9.2. Apps containing asset catalogs built with Xcode 10 whose deployment target was set to iOS 9.0, 9.1 or 9.2 would produce content incompatible with the runtimes of those iOS versions. Rebuilding the application with Xcode 10.1 resolves this issue. (44535967)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_1_beta_2_release_notes?language=objc

Comment: Is it means the app won't crash whose deployment target was iOS8.0? But my app's deployment target was 8.0, and still crash with iOS9.0. Why?

Comment: Why do you assume that if it crashes for 9.0, it wouldn't crash on 8.0? Wait for Xcode 12.1 to GM

Comment: @Coeur we can't submit an app that  supports XS, XS Max, XR and compatible with iOS 9 with Xcode 10.1 ?

Comment: @samir Xcode 10.1 solved the problem, but was released just 1.5 days ago. My comment was from 4 weeks ago.

Comment: I just released a new version of my app using Xcode 10.1 and I'm still seeing crashes on devices running iOS 9.0-9.2. I tested this bug when it said it was fixed in the release notes and it did seem to fix it, but it looks like the final version of Xcode 10.1 doesn't fix this issue. Or not all instances of it.

Comment: This bug has not been fixed in XCode 10.1.

Comment: Apple just modified their release notes for 10.1 to make this issue open once again:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_1_release_notes?language=objc

Comment: From the Xcode 10.2 beta release notes, it fixed for "local or enterprise distribution", not sure if it fixed for non-enterprise distribution build.

Comment: It should be fixed for everyone once Apple allows people to upload builds using Xcode 10.2 to the AppStore. That means only when 10.2 is publicly released.

Comment: Can anyone confirm whether it is fixed in Xcode 10.2 or not?

Comment: According to the release notes, it is fixed. I cannot personally test.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of waiting for Apple to fix, submit using Xcode 9 while using NSInvocation for the new API. It involves more code but your users will be happy.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. When you compile against an old SDK, Apple runs its frameworks in a compatibility mode. If you then proceed to call API that is unexpected in said compatibility mode, you can expect your app to misbehave at best and crash at worst. At this point, the best thing to do is temporarily disable support for < 9.3

Comment: My app is already approved without any weird crashes. My app is using new complications for Apple Watch Series 4 which I have implemented using NSInvocation calls.

Comment: @LeoNatan great explanations, do you have the source that explains this mechanism please I can't manage to find it my self on apple website :S

Comment: Source: experience of over 8 years in the iOS ecosystem. Apps run in compat mode when compiled against old SDKs.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for Xcode 10.1 Archive

Set The build system as Legacy Build System instead of Default build system

File -> Workspace Settings -> Build System: change to Legacy Build System

I test it on my own app and it works well.

Hope Apple can fix this crash soon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been resolved.

> **Asset Catalog**
>
> **Resolved Issues**
>
> Resolved an issue that affected app compatibility with iOS 9.0, 9.1, and 9.2 when distributing an app on the App Store. App asset catalogs built using Xcode 10 with a deployment target of iOS 9.0, 9.1 or 9.2 produce content incompatible with the runtimes of those iOS versions when distributed via the App Store. Rebuild and resubmit the app using Xcode 10.1 to resolve the issue. (44535967, 45723580, 45723189)
>   [Xcode 10.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_1_release_notes?language=objc)