# My app crashed in iOS9.1 & 9.2 device which upload by Xcode 10 official version Seed

Tags: xcode10, ios9.1, ios9.2

1. update my xcode to version 10
2. archive my app and upload to App Store use Xcode 10
3. This problem occured. It's random, high frequency in iOS 9.1 & 9.2

Comment: The question with same crash:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364231/our-app-crashed-in-ios9-which-upload-by-xcode-10-gm-seed

Comment: Xcode version diff , GM & Official

Answer (score 1):

this  problem is caused by Xcode 10 ,you should use Xcode 9.4 to archive ~