# Why my app which archived by Xcode10.0 downloaded from AppStore crash with iOS9.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

I notice this new Xcode beta release note. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_1_beta_2_release_notes?language=objc

> Resolves an issue that affected app compatibility with iOS 9.0, 9.1 and 9.2. Apps containing asset catalogs built with Xcode 10 whose deployment target was set to iOS 9.0, 9.1 or 9.2 would produce content incompatible with the runtimes of those iOS versions. Rebuilding the application with Xcode 10.1 resolves this issue. (44535967)

My app's deployment target was 8.0（not 9.0, 9.1 and 9.2）, but it still crashed when downloaded from App Store. Do I misunderstand this release note? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Xcode 10

Comment: Related: [our app crashed in iOS 9 which upload by Xcode 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364231/our-app-crashed-in-ios-9-which-upload-by-xcode-10)

Comment: Just use Xcode 10.1 now that it got released.

Comment: Not fixed in Xcode 10.1 either. Apple amended their release notes and how has this again under "Known Issues" section.

Comment: @dnkoutso I see that. Terrible!